# How can I test how my in-app pricing looks like in other currencies?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I use Google Play Billing library for an in-app product.

When using my app, I always see my original pricing, in my country's currency. The price appears on the Google Play purchase popup, and where I use `getPrice()`.

I would like to experience the way the formatted price looks like in various countries, to make sure it looks fine with my own UI and the with the billing UI. And also just to see in my own eyes that the automatic conversions works.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

With the following steps I was able to achieve this:

1. Set up a test account on Google Play: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/test
2. Use a VPN with the country you need on your device.
3. Open your app and check the prices.

*Sometimes, the UI may not be updated (sometimes until the next day, sometimes only after a reboot), but the prices can always be seen when buying.*

Edit: To instantly update the UI of prices and currencies in the app, simply clear the Google Play cache.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that if there will be no better choice. I was hoping there is some straight forward way to do it. Anyway, regrading the delay, have you tried stopping Google play and clearing its cache? And doing the same regarding your app?

Comment: @DoronBen-Ari, no, I haven't tried any ways to avoid the delay since I didn't need it. I'll be able to test your suggestions in a few days, if you haven't tried it yourself yet.

Comment: @DoronBen, clearing the Google Play cache works like a charm, pricing and currency UI updates instantly after clearing.